# How to use callback of setState in some places not all via hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-state

I want to set a state and sometimes I want to do something after that and sometimes **not**!

how can I do that with **hooks**?

**sometimes** I want to call a function or do something after setting that:

```
 this.setState({inputValue:'someValue'},()=>{
    //do something
    })
```

**but sometimes not**

```
this.setState({inputValue:'someAnotherValue'})
```

then I couldn't use of useEffect like this because **I don't want to do something after setting that all the time**:

```
useEffect(()=>{

    //do something 

},[inputValue])
```

Comment: put relevant condition in useEffect or add another state like ''doSomethingState" and add it to useEffect Dependencies when you'll change the state: useEffect(()=>{

    //do something 

},[doSomethingState])

Comment: if I use of doSomethingState, it won't make the component become a mess with the passage of time?

Comment: As i said, you can also put condition in logic body of hook,useEffect(()=>{

    //if do something 

},[inputValue])

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(inputValue == someValue){
        //do something
    }
}, [inputValue])
```